# vitualbox NAT stopped working after Ubuntu upgrade to 12.10

Tags: nat, virtualbox-networking

After upgrading to 12.10 from 12.04 none of my virtualbox virtual machines can use NAT to access the network.  I have tried vboxmanage modifyvm  --natdnsproxy1 on and/or --natdnshostresolver1 on, but still doesn't work.  What can I do to resolve this?  I have also upgraded to Virtualbox 4.2.4 to attempt to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but without updating to 12.10: I already was in 12.10 last Wednesday, the last time I used the virtualmachine, but on Sunday I couldn't access the network from any virtual OS (tried both Windows 7 and Windows 8). Also tried to update from virtualbox 4.1 (bundled with ubuntu) with virtualbox 4.2 from the Oracle website, but nothing changed.

I guess an Ubuntu update broke something.

I've tried an [answer from another thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/212235/17299) and it does work

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "name" --natdnshostresolver1 on
VBoxManage modifyvm "name" --natdnsproxy1 on
```

(PS: I couldn't add this as a comment to the original question, don't have enough reputation, but thought it could be useful)

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons it does not work directly from 12.10 is here https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10864

VirtualBoxes uses hosts /etc/resolv.conf file to map dns into its internal dhcp, thus blocking name resolution. In the waiting for a fix I had to manually setup dns servers on hosts resolv.conf file